# Find all duplicate groups where duplicate means groups containing same members

Tags: sql, postgresql, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I need a SQL query to find all duplicate groups. By duplicate, i mean any group that has the same members. So formally the problem can be written: Return all sets of channel_ids where in a given set containing m channels: channel i through m have contain the same members. I have a join table groups_members with columns group_id, user_id and a users table and a groups table. Thanks for any help.

Comment: lol, no it is not homework. the formality is just b/c it is clear to understand with a formal problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the WHERE IN clause - and then in the subquery use GROUP BY with the HAVING clause (you can say something like HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 to find duplicates).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. I finally figured it out.

`select array_agg(DISTINCT a.channel_id) as channels, a.members from (select channel_id, array_agg(user_id) as members from users_channels group by channel_id) a JOIN (select channel_id, array_agg(user_id) as members from users_channels group by channel_id) b ON a.members = b.members AND a.channel_id <> b.channel_id group by a.members;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a full join and see whether any of the user_id's are null, which means there's a user that's in one group but not the other

```
select gm1.id, gm2.id from group_members gm1
full join group_members gm2 on gm2.user_id = gm1.user_id
where gm1.id < gm2.id
group by gm1.id, gm2.id
having count(case when gm1.user_id is null 
  or gm2.user_id is null then 1 end) = 0
```

Another way using 2 `not exists` clauses to make sure that a user that is not in the other group's users list does not not exist.

```
select g.* from groups g1
join groups g2 on g2.id < g1.id
where not exists (
    select 1 from group_members gm1
    left join group_members gm2 on gm1.user_id = gm2.user_id and gm2.id = g2.id
    where gm1.group_id = g1.id
    and gm2.user_id is null
) and not exists (
    select 1 from group_members gm1
    left join group_members gm2 on gm1.user_id = gm2.user_id and gm2.id = g1.id
    where gm1.group_id = g2.id
    and gm2.user_id is null 
)
```